# Will completing the Cafe missions make me more money?

Tags: assassins-creed-unity

Do you get additional income to your chest for doing the side missions from the renovated places?

Comment: I think you do as the missions generally improve the state of the cafe, which logically means it should make more money. Although I haven't experimented so have no evidence to back that up :)

Comment: @DavidYell - I know the cafe missions give you more money but I did not know if the renovated buildings side missions did.

Comment: They are one and the same. The buildings you revonate are cafes throughout the city. They serve as social hubs where you can find your online friends, people you've met and serve as fast travel locations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've been poking around in guides and forums and the answer is **Yes**

> Amounts (of Income) are small at first, but will increase if you renovate
>   additional Cafes and **complete Cafe Theatre missions.**

There are more ways of increasing Income however, here's a list:

- Renovating Cafes
- Completing the Cafe Theatre Missions
- Collecting Mementos from Missions

Here's a [Forum Thread](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/772634-assassins-creed-unity/70555215) that confirms what you want to know.

If you're interested in knowing more about getting money on Assassin's Creed you can read [this](http://www.primagames.com/games/assassins-creed-unity/tips/how-get-more-money-assassins-creed-unity).